# How can I change the background color of label when its value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the background color of label when its value is changed. My code do not work correctly. How I can do this?

HTML:

```
<label class="label-default lb_status label-danger"> confirmed </label>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
        var status=$('.lb_status').val();
        if (status == "confirmed") {
            $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-success');
        }
        else if (status == "pending") {
            $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-warning');

        }
        else if (status == "declined") {
            $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-danger');

}
```

Comment: `label` doesn't have a `value`, use `text()` instead, you'll probably need to `$.trim()` it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/L3xz0s97/

```
<label class="label-default lb_status label-danger">confirmed</label>
<script>
    $(function () {
    var status=$('.lb_status').text();
    if (status == "confirmed") {
        $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-success');
    }
    else if (status == "pending") {
        $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-warning');

    }
    else if (status == "declined") {
        $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-danger');

    }
    })
</script>
```

Function is only called on startup.

Comment: That's not working, where is the input? Maybe I'm confused at what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is only called on startup. What you need here is a jquery change handler:
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Here is a working example, but please note that change() only works on input elements:
https://jsfiddle.net/g99013r9/

```
$(".lb_status").change(function() {        
    var status=$('.lb_status').val();
    console.log(status);
    if (status == "confirmed") {
        $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-success');
    }
    else if (status == "pending") {
        $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-warning');

    }
    else if (status == "declined") {
        $('.lb_status').removeClass('label-default').addClass('label-danger');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!